# Basepairs from the Human Genome Project

Tags: research, genome

How do you use [GenBank](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genbank/) to pull the count of actual base pairs (and actual bases) that were uploaded week-by-week across the entire [Human Genome Project](https://www.genome.gov/10001477/human-genome-projects-fiveyear-plan-19911995/) in its early years 1990-1998?

Ideally, we want to be able see the count of base pairs as reflected in this graph - and pull the base pairs too.

[image]